# Did Quake 2 come out in Denmark two days before the USA?

Tags: quake-2

In [The Warez Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5zA1Zkz5DUE&t=29s) by Mark Borle, one lyric states that "*Quake 2 came out in Denmark two days before the USA*"

Is this true?

Comment: Can downvoters please explain the dislike for this question?

Comment: The downvotes are likely due to a couple of issues; there seems to be no research effort involved in the question, nor does there seem to be much usefulness in this information.  I can't say for sure that's why people have downvoted, but reading the tooltip is usually a good bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

Windows release dates from [The Cutting Room Floor](https://tcrf.net/Quake_II) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quake_II):

- WW (Worldwide): 12/7/97
- NA (North America): 12/9/97

As far as I know, Denmark is in the world, so ***Quake II* came out in Denmark two days before the US**.

*Thanks a lot to [Smock in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354425/did-quake-2-come-out-in-denmark-two-days-before-the-usa#comment499110_354428); I got this wrong until they put a link to The Cutting Room Floor saying when it actually came out worldwide.*

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia article is lacking citations for these other than for the Xbox release date, so this could be off.

Comment: This is incomplete. The Windows edition of the game was certainly out in Worldwide before 2007.

Comment: According to this site it was internationally released on 7th December, 1997 which is 2 days before the NA date above (https://tcrf.net/Quake_II)

Comment: @Smock Is it alright if I steal your source to update my answer?

Comment: @Chaosblessed go ahead :)